# Help identify this serif typeface

Tags: font-identification, serif

I'm trying to find out what font is below.  I originally thought perhaps a Garamond family or Times Pro but I'm stumped.  The numbers usually are the dead giveaway with the above possibilities.  Anyone have any guesses?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Do you have better quality image of the same?

Comment: "The numbers usually are the dead giveaway" means?

Comment: Anyway, I tried to find unfortunately no luck. You can try these similar fonts if you want: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Markazi+Text?category=Serif,Display&preview.text=The%20future%20of%20real%20estate&preview.text_type=custom&preview.size=65 and https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Halant?category=Serif,Display&preview.text=The%20future%20of%20real%20estate&preview.text_type=custom&preview.size=65

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this font before, but can't recall the name now. Almost looks like Galaxie Copernicus though https://vllg.com/constellation/galaxie-copernicus

Comment: Try using [My Fonts Whatthefont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) - some results are close.

Comment: @Luciano good find. Everything matches it's just that height of "h" seems a little more in OP's sample image right? I don't see any other difference.

Comment: @BillyKerr I had gone through all no luck.

Comment: @vikas - hmmm, when I tried whatthefont suggested a very close match - Geller Headline Semi-bold.

Comment: Oh yeah *similar* can be found.

Comment: @Vikas - yeah, but it is very similar. Might even be a match, but it's hard to tell for sure because the original is a bit blurry.

Comment: @BillyKerr the one Luciano found is extremely similar.

Comment: @BillyKerr also the one Copilot has found is also extremely similar. Could be exact match.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be [Tiempos Semibold](https://klim.co.nz/retail-fonts/tiempos-text/) by Klim Type Foundry.

[image: Tiempos Semibold]

Comment: 1 upvote because I feel it's a perfect match.

Comment: It’s Tiempos Semibold, but you should include a link and, preferably, screenshot when answering font-identification questions so people don’t have to go Googling to check if it’s actually right or not. I’ve added both for you.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Is it Tiempos Semibold Text, Fine, or Headline family?

Comment: I'm not sure; the image is a bit fuzzy so it's hard to say. My guess is most likely Text or Headline.